# Laravel nova save Resource field with belongsTo

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I would like save a resource in Laravel Nova.

I have actually 2 resources and 2 model:

**Customer** and **CustomerType**

Customer has these fields:

```
Text::make('Vat')
   ->rules('required', 'string', 'max:254')
   ->creationRules('unique:customers,vat')
   ->updateRules('unique:customers,vat,{{resourceId}}'),

BelongsTo::make('Type', 'customer_type', 'App\Nova\CustomerType'),
```

And the Model of Customer has relationship **customer_type**:

```
public function customer_type(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\CustomerType', 'id', 'type');
    }
```

When I open create **Customer resource view**, I see correctly the list of types in a select box but When I try to set type and save it return SQL error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'type' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `customers` (`vat`, `id`, `name`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (vat, ?, test, 2019-07-31 10:41:05,
>   2019-07-31 10:41:05))

How should Add the **type** to the nova resource save?

I also tried to change name of Relationship from **customer_type** to **type**, but it return same error.

My db for now is:

**Customer** table

- id
- vat
- type

**customer_type** table:

- id
- slug

**EDIT**

I have tried also to put

```
BelongsTo::make('CustomerType'),
```

In field and Customer model:

```
public function customertype(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\CustomerType', 'id', 'type');
    }
```

But same error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others dev.

I've found my error.

In my model I've inverted the foreignkey and ownerkey of relationship:

instead of:

```
public function customertype(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\CustomerType', 'id', 'type');
    }
```

**Should be**

```
public function customertype(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\CustomerType', 'type', 'id');
    }
```